# Calling an end point to get data from NodeJs program

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js

I have an application written in NodeJs. I need to make a call to an end-point (http:\localhost:9900\get\employee - asp.net web-api) and get the data back. What options I have ? Can this be done using [promise](https://github.com/kriskowal/q)

Please provide your suggestions. I might use browserify module and might run the code in browser. Does it make sense to use JQuery Ajax call ?

Comment: The promise library you linked to, `Q` would do so with the q-io package (same author) using q-http. Otherwise, you can use Bluebird and simply promisify the HTTP module found here http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback , or use it directly (although promises help).

Answer (score -2):

You can use restclient extention in Firefox and postman extention in chrome to make call to any of the urls.

Comment: Completely irrelevant to the question, the question is asking how to make a request from NodeJS with promises.